# How can I map a multiple Joined Table per class strategy using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Consider a database with three tables: PET, CAT, and EXTENSION.CAT where Pet is a base class of Cat and Extension.Cat contains an extension table with additional properties for Cat. Nhibernate allows modeling the Pet - Cat relationship using something like this:

```
<class name="Pet" table = "PET">
    <id name="id" column="ID">...</id>
    <property name="name"/>
    <property name="age"/>
    <joined-subclass name="Cat" table="CAT">
        <key column="ID"/>
        <property name="isMouser"/>
    </joined-subclass> </class>
```

and the Cat - CatEx relationship like this:

```
<class name="Cat" table="CAT">
    <id name="id" column="ID">...</id>
    <property name="isMouser"/>
    <join table="CAT" schema="EXTENSION" >
        <key column="ID"/>
        <property name="fuzziness"/>
        <property name="cuteness"/>
    </join>
</class>
```

So, although I'd assume the following should work, it doesn't:

```
<class name="Pet" table = "PET">
    <id name="id" column="ID">...</id>
    <property name="name"/>
    <property name="age"/>
    <joined-subclass name="Cat" table="CAT">
        <key column="ID" />
        <property name="isMouser"/>
        <join table="CAT" schema="EXTENSION" >
            <key column="ID"/>
            <property name="fuzziness"/>
            <property name="cuteness"/>
        </join>
    </joined-subclass>
</class>
```

The Nhibernate documentation doesn't describe this scenario. What is the proper way to model a multiple-table per class hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of modeling this scenario is to use the implicit polymorphism pattern.

```
<class name="Cat" table = "PET">
    <id name="id" column="ID">...</id>
    <property name="name"/>
    <property name="age"/>
    <join table="CAT">
        <key column="id"/>
        <property name="isMouser"/>
    </join>
    <join table="CAT" schema="EXTENSION" >
        <key column="id"/>
        <property name="fuzziness"/>
        <property name="cuteness"/>
    </join>
</class>
```

The key factor here being that the parent table (PET) is the first table referenced, although we are modeling the Cat class. This scenario effectively gives us multiple tables per derived class.

One potential issue is where the join columns names do not match, and a property for the child table column exists in the mapped class. NHibernate requires these additional class properties to have a mapping. Adding  "generated=insert", "insert=false", and "update=false" attributes to the child table's property tells NHibernate to make the property read-only.

```
<class name="Cat" table = "PET">
    <id name="petid" column="PETID">...</id>
    <property name="name"/>
    <property name="age"/>
    <join table="CAT">
        <key column="catid"/>
        <property name="isMouser"/>
        <property name="catid" generated="insert" insert="false" update="false" />
    </join>
    <join table="CAT" schema="EXTENSION" >
        <key column="catexid"/>
        <property name="fuzziness"/>
        <property name="cuteness"/>
        <property name="catexid" generated="insert" insert="false" update="false" />
    </join>
</class>
```